# Lightbox not working properly on server

Tags: jquery, webserver, lightbox

I made a portfolio part using Lightbox plugin, it is working perfectly on my computer but when i uploaded on godaddy's server, plugin simply is not working.

Here is the website http://thehouseofseven.com/

Comment: Getting a 404 error on jquery.lightbox-0.5.js. Make sure the file is uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make '`js`' upper case:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
                                    ^^--------------------Upper case
```